# PHP Вернуть массив следующих дней

Tags: php, функции

Нужно реализовать следующую функцию:

```
get_next_days($day_now, $count)
```

В которой можно указать $day_now, например "Fri" и count, от которого зависит количество возвращаемых дней, начиная с "Fri", например, если я введу Fri и 3, то должен получить Fri, Sat, Sun

Буду очень благодарен за примеры или готовую функцию! Очень долго ломаю над этим голову!

Comment: Что вы сами сделали для решения вашей проблемы? Код в студию!

Comment: Ясно же что ничего не сделал.

Comment: А если ввести `$count` 7 или 8? Что должно получиться?

Answer (score 1):

> *Буду очень благодарен за примеры или готовую функцию*

Есть готовый класс DateTime:

```
$next_days = get_next_days('Fri', 3);
echo $next_days;

function get_next_days($day_now, $count): String
{
    $days = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
        $days[] = (new DateTime("$day_now +$i days"))->format('D');
    }
    return join(', ', $days);
}
```

Результат:

```
Fri, Sat, Sun
```

---

**UPD:** Вариант для возврата массива:

```
$next_days = get_next_days('Fri', 3);
print_r($next_days);

function get_next_days($now, $count, $days = []): Array
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $days[] = (new DateTime("$now +$i days"))->format('D');
    }
    return $days;
}
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Fri
    [1] => Sat
    [2] => Sun
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Так тоже можно:

```
<?php
function get_next_days($day_now, $count)
{
    $days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
    $idx = array_search($day_now, $days);
    if ($idx === false) {
        return [];
    }
    $ret = [$day_now];
    if (!--$count) {
        return $ret;
    }
    $day_next = $days[++$idx === count($days)? 0: $idx];
    return array_merge($ret, get_next_days($day_next, $count));
}
echo implode(", ", get_next_days('Fri', 3)); // Fri, Sat, Sun
echo implode(", ", get_next_days('Sat', 3)); // Sat, Sun, Mon
echo implode(", ", get_next_days('Sat', 8)); // Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну вы ребята даете ))

```
function get_next_days($day_now, $count, $format = 'D') // можно передать Mon, Monday, Today etc.
{
    if(!($day_now = strtotime($day_now))) {
        return false; // если нам непонятно что пришло возвращаем ошибку
    }
    $days = [date($format,$day_now)];
    for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) { 
        $day_now = strtotime('tomorrow',$day_now);
        $days[] = date($format,$day_now);
    }
    return implode(', ', $days);
}
```